# Sum values in a list in pandas data

Tags: pandas

i am a newbie in python and need your support. I have a below output from test data frame

```
     LS    last  height weight
0   88+2    Doe  5.5    130
1   90+2    Bo   6.0    150
```

output[]

```
0    [88, 2]
1    [90, 2]
```

I'm trying to sum the values in the 'LS' column. is the output for LS columns should be sum ie 90 & 92.
I split them into a list and trying to sum them

Can you please suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

We can try `eval`

```
df.LS=pd.eval(df.LS)
#pd.eval(df.LS)
#Out[394]: [90, 92]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LS': [[88, 2], [90,2]]
})
df['sum'] = df['LS'].apply(sum)
print(df)

        LS  sum
0  [88, 2]   90
1  [90, 2]   92
```

Comment: Ok cool. You might want to re-word the question, it's confusing what you want to do, is the input dataframe [88,2] or 88+2